# AndroidTest Failed while running from command line :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest

Tags: android, android-espresso, spring-test, android-instrumentation, spring-android

I'm using android spring `RestTemplate` for making REST service calls on my app. I added android Instrumentation test which includes mocking the REST service calls.
All my test are running fine while running from android studio, but the test failed to load spring mock class while running from terminal using

```
   ./gradlew clean :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
```

The spring test dependency on build.gradle

```
    androidTestCompile("org.springframework:spring-test:3.2.8.RELEASE")
```

If i change to `compile` instead of `androidTestCompile` , the android test are running fine from terminal . 
Since i don't want this dependency on my production APK any help , appreciated.

This the log while starting the test

> 08-05 00:04:12.585 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting
>   E/TestLoader: Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.asm.commons.JSRInlinerAdapter 08-05 00:04:12.587
>   22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader: Could not find
>   class: org.springframework.asm.commons.TryCatchBlockSorter 08-05
>   00:04:12.593 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask 08-05
>   00:04:12.593 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.cglib.transform.AbstractTransformTask 08-05
>   00:04:12.603 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter
>   08-05 00:04:12.610 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting
>   E/TestLoader: Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.core.io.ResourceEditor 08-05 00:04:12.611
>   22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader: Could not find
>   class: org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourceArrayPropertyEditor
>   08-05 00:04:12.617 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting
>   E/TestLoader: Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.mock.http.MockHttpInputMessage 08-05 00:04:12.618
>   22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader: Could not find
>   class: org.springframework.mock.http.MockHttpOutputMessage 08-05
>   00:04:12.618 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.mock.http.client.MockClientHttpRequest 08-05
>   00:04:12.618 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.mock.http.client.MockClientHttpResponse 08-05
>   00:04:12.618 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.mock.jndi.ExpectedLookupTemplate 08-05
>   00:04:12.619 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContext 08-05 00:04:12.619
>   22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader: Could not find
>   class: org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContextBuilder 08-05
>   00:04:12.619 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.mock.web.DelegatingServletInputStream 08-05
>   00:04:12.619 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.mock.web.DelegatingServletOutputStream 08-05
>   00:04:12.620 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class: org.springframework.mock.web.MockBodyContent
>   08-05 00:04:12.620 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting
>   E/TestLoader: Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.mock.web.MockExpressionEvaluator 08-05
>   00:04:12.620 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class: org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain
>   08-05 00:04:12.620 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting
>   E/TestLoader: Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterConfig 08-05 00:04:12.620
>   22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader: Could not find
>   class: org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest 08-05
>   00:04:12.621 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse 08-05
>   00:04:12.621 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class: org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpSession
>   08-05 00:04:12.621 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting
>   E/TestLoader: Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.mock.web.MockJspWriter 08-05 00:04:12.621
>   22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader: Could not find
>   class: org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile 08-05
>   00:04:12.621 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartHttpServletRequest 08-05
>   00:04:12.622 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class: org.springframework.mock.web.MockPageContext
>   08-05 00:04:12.622 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting
>   E/TestLoader: Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.mock.web.MockRequestDispatcher 08-05 00:04:12.623
>   22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader: Could not find
>   class: org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletConfig 08-05
>   00:04:12.623 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class: org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext
>   08-05 00:04:12.628 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting
>   E/TestLoader: Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.mock.web.PassThroughFilterChain 08-05 00:04:12.628
>   22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader: Could not find
>   class: org.springframework.mock.web.portlet.MockActionRequest 08-05
>   00:04:12.629 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.mock.web.portlet.MockActionResponse 08-05
>   00:04:12.629 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/TestLoader:
>   Could not find class: org.springframework.mock.web.portlet.MockBaseURL
>   08-05 00:04:12.629 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting
>   E/TestLoader: Could not find class:
>   org.springframework.mock.web.portlet.MockCacheControl 08-05
>   00:04:12.630 22274-22302/com.libin.androiduitesting E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
>                                                                               Process: com.libin.androiduitesting, PID: 22274
>                                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.springframework.mock.web.portlet.MockClientDataRequest
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.doLoadClass(TestLoader.java:92)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.loadIfTest(TestLoader.java:113)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.loadClassesFromClassPath(TestRequestBuilder.java:801)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:747)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:354)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:260)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)

Comment: What about `testCompile`?

Comment: change `androidTestCompile` to `testCompile` as @cricket_007 said. Is it working?

Comment: No. How does that work?, dependencies added to testCompile are included only for unit test. I'm running androidTest. It won't include the spring test library on androidTest

Comment: add if you could your's build.gradle's file. Nowadays everyone who wants to help you looks like magician, ok?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are missing mocking classes which are neccesary for testing. Try dowloading spring-test jar and check if all mocking classes are inside - for example, it should export class `org.springframework.mock.web.portlet.MockClientDataRequest` from package `org.springframework.mock.web.portlet`.

You can be using some unfortunate jar build where dependiencies for mocking classes were lost like in [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-mvc/issues/41).

Also you can try updating spring framework, the latest is already 4.3.2.

Comment: No I'm not missing the classes. Sees its getting removed while lodaing the test for the whole module when starting to run. Everything is fine if the test is running for individual class or package